# Visual Studio exports everytime a Setup if i puplish my program. how to change? c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there a way to compile my own program without having Visual Studio create a setup file? Would like a single .exe file.
i dont understand why my program have to be installed.
It's annoying after every update, first deinstall the old one, and I also don't think it's neat

This is what i got after puplish.

i saw it on many other projects from other people, they always had a single .exe.

[image]

MY IDE

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have click once enabled

Comment: This delete only my .dll's before puplish. it makes the program 
unusable if i deactivate it.. and I still have a setup file + folder and application.. only a few dlls are missing

Answer (score 1):

Environment:Vs 2019 and above

Project Framework:.Net Core 3.1 and above

3.1 Console Application:

[image]

1. Click Folder and Next:

[image]

2. Click Folder and Next:

[image]

3. Click Finish:

[image]

4. Show all settings->self-contained->win-x64->produce a single file:

[image]

5. That's the exe.

[image]

Comment: i use WinForms .Net Framework.. it doenst work on this way.. but i also dont understand why there are different ways on the same IDE :/ But Thanks i notice this

Comment: but it didn't help me because i work with .net frame everything looks completely different than you show me on your pictures on .core, if i create a project with .core net i have this page too. but with .net framework you dont have this. you can just puplish and then it popups a litte window. not like yours. thats called assistant for puplish...

Comment: @ShiiikK Could you show post-launch screenshots of "Other People"? By the way, show their environment configuration. I might be able to help you. Thanks!